# Change diagonal of a non square matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

Suppose I have this kind of matrix:

```
1 2 3
3 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
3 2 3
```

How do I add a diagonal of ones into this? Is there an easy way?
To show what I mean:

```
1 2 3
3 1 3
4 5 1
1 8 9
3 1 3
```

Comment: so you mean 'replace' and not an `+` operation, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html), you don't even need reshape!

```
[r, c] = size(m);
m(1:c:end) = 1;
m =

     1     2     3
     4     1     6
     7     8     1
     1    11    12
    13     1    15
```

If `r < c`, this is the best I got:

```
if r < c
   n = m';
   n(1:r:end) = 1;
   m = n';
else
   m(1:c:end) = 1;
end
```

Comment: @jkshah: Honestly, I can't find a way to do that *and* avoid `if` using just linear indexing. I updated the answer. If you have a better suggestion, *shoot*! =)

Comment: @RobertP. +1. seems perfect! I didn't have better solution, but was trying to make it complete. Appreciate your thinking.

Comment: @RobertP. You don't even need the row number: why not just `m(1:size(m,2):end) = 1`? Note, however, that your solution only works for r >= c

Answer (score 2):

This is a general solution, using linear indexing and modulo operations:

```
[R C] = size(m);
ii = 1:R;
jj = mod(ii,C);
jj(jj==0) = C;
m(ii+(jj-1)*R) = 1; %// or m(sub2ind([R C],ii,jj)) = 1;
```

For example,

```
m =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
    13    14    15
    16    17    18
    19    20    21
```

gets transformed into

```
m =

     1     2     3
     4     1     6
     7     8     1
     1    11    12
    13     1    15
    16    17     1
     1    20    21
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s=min(size(m))
m(1:s,1:s)=eye(s)+(~eye(s).*m(1:s,1:s))
```

Comment: I tried this on m=[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9;10,11,12;13,14,15] but only the upper diagonal was replaced.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a shorter version without comparing the number of rows to the number of columns you can try this (Assuming that you want to make the diagonal elements of an arbitrary matrix M equal to 1):

```
M(logical(speye(size(M)))) = 1
```